# meaning of “You don’t get to bang your spoon on the table and somehow you get your way.”

Tags: sentence-structure

[source](https://www.vox.com/2018/6/12/17450974/trump-kim-jong-un-summit-winners)

> “You don’t get to bang your spoon on the table and somehow you get
>   your way.”

I roughly understand the major meaning. I don't understand some details.

1.

> You don't get (what you want) by banging your spoon ...

right?

2.

> somehow you get your way

What is the meaning of "get your way"?

Comment: The entire structure, if you didn't grasp it already, is "acting like a child isn't an effective method of negotiation" - like a 2-year-old in a high-chair, wanting more breakfast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are pretty much right. “You don’t get to bang your spoon on the table and somehow you get your way.” means:

> You have a choice, either you can throw tantrums like a child, or we can negotiate how things can be better for you, but you can't have both.

2. "Get you own way" means that you get what you want in spite of what other people want or say.

Comment: Can you find some examples of "You don't get to ..."?

Comment: Oh, "Get you own way" is an idiom. I didn't expect.
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/zhs/%E8%AF%8D%E5%85%B8/%E8%8B%B1%E8%AF%AD-%E6%B1%89%E8%AF%AD-%E7%AE%80%E4%BD%93/get-your-own-way

Comment: @马化腾  Actually I have never heard this particular expression before. I suspect that President Obama (or more likely his speech writer) was the first person to use this expression.  The idiom is "get your own way." For the record, "getting your own way" is not always a bad thing, it depends upon the outcome.